# Can't add image using ImageIcon to jTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon

I trying to add image using `ImageIcon` class to `jTable` cell , but i get in the cell `sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@196a4632` where it supposed to display image in the cell
the code i tried :

```
     JTable jTable;
 String[] columns={"Page No","Chapter","Image"};
 Object[][] rows={{1,4,null},{2,7,null}}}
 public Tab_ImgIcn(){
 ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));
           jTable= new JTable(rows, columns);
           jTable.setValueAt(icon.getImage(), 0,3);
           JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jTable);
           frame.add(jps);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). We can help if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to override `getColumnClass()` on the table model, and return `ImageIcon.class` for the column with the `ImageIcon`. If you don't, the renderer will show the `toString()`, as the default column class type will be `Object`. See [How to use Tables: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

For example

```
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));
String[] columns={"Page No","Chapter","Image"};
Object[][] rows={{1,4,icon},{2,7,icon}};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch(column) {
            case 0:
            case 1: return Integer.class;
            case 2: return ImageIcon.class;
            default: return Object.class;
        }
    }
};
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```