# double clicking on an imageicon in jtable makes the imageIcon dissapear

Tags: java, mysql, image, swing, blob

I have a `JTable` where i fetch data from db and display. One of the columns is a `blob` oject type and it contains a image(if present ,else null ).
I also have a double click event handler for the JTable so that when user double clicks only on the image,a new `JFrame` is opened which shows the image in full screen.
The problem i am facing is that when the user double clicks the image is shown in new window as expected, however the imageIcon which was earlier visible in the `JTable` gets dissapeared and instead a string is shown having value as `javax.swing.ImageIcon@1ce5bc4d`. So how do i get back the imageIcon after completion of the double click event ?
Here is my code(the column `payment_receipt` is the blob):

```
String query = "Select payment_date,payment_amt,payment_receipt from fooTable";
    conn = dbTest.connect();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

        //names of columns
        Vector<String>columnNames = new Vector<String>();

        for(int i=1;i<=columns;i++)
        {
            columnNames.add(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i));
        }

        //data of table
         Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
         while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
                for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columns; columnIndex++) 
                {
                    if (columnIndex ==3 ) //starting index is 1
                    {  // image column
                        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("payment_receipt");
                        if(blob!=null)
                        {

                            int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  

                            byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                            blob.free();
                            BufferedImage img=null;
                            try {
                                img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                                icon = new ImageIcon(img);

                                vector.addElement(icon);
                            } 
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        vector.addElement(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
                    }

            }
           data.add(vector);
         }
         table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames))
                 {
                    @Override
                    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                        if(column==2)
                        {
                                return ImageIcon.class;
                        }
                        else
                            return Object.class;
                    }
                };

        table.setRowHeight(200);//to display the receipt
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(this.getPreferredSize());
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
            {
                JTable table = (JTable)mouseEvent.getSource();
                Point point = mouseEvent.getPoint();
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);//the index of row where the double click event too place
                int column = table.columnAtPoint(point);
                if(mouseEvent.getClickCount()==2 && table.getSelectedRow() !=-1)
                {
                    if(column==2)//image column,so open image in full screen
                    {
                        Object obj = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                        if(obj!=null)
                        {
                            if(obj.getClass().equals(ImageIcon.class))
                            {
                                ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)obj;
                                jf = new JFrame();
                                jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                                jf.setBounds(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds());
                                jf.add(new JLabel(icon));
                                jf.setVisible(true);
                                loadPaymentsTable();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No image available");
                                loadPaymentsTable();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No image available");
                                loadPaymentsTable();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please add which programing language you are using as tag

Comment: You might consider reducing the complexity of the sample code you pasted; it's got a lot in there that likely has nothing to do with the problem you are facing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution by changing the ImageIcon.class to Icon.class here:

```
@Override
                public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                    if(column==2)
                    {
                            return Icon.class;
                    }
                    else
                        return Object.class;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using the same `ImageIcon` in two `JFrame`s is causing the issue; make a copy of the image for the new window.

Native resources used by java components, especially images and BufferedImages are sensitive to re-use and disposal.

Comment: i tried this :
`ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)obj;
         ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage());
jf.add(new JLabel(icon2));`
but of no avail

Comment: what i can't comprehend is why the imageIcon which is visible earlier in the jTable getting converted into some string like path javax.swing.ImageIcon@1ce5bc4d and what does it represent ?

Comment: That looks like a memory address. Getting the image from the previous ImageIcon isn't copying it since they are both referencing the same image (just wrapped).  You need to create a new BufferedImage, passing the dimensions of the existing image, and draw the existing image into the new one by getting the graphics object, drawing onto it, then disposing the graphics object.